# Error when using <form:input path="xx"> filled by a set

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a class called Menu, with a field called voceMenuList, that contains the menu items like "Home", "contact" etc.

```
public class Menu implements Serializable{

private Set<VoceMenu> voceMenuList;

public void setVoceMenuList(Set<VoceMenu> voceMenuList) {
        this.voceMenuList = voceMenuList;}

public Set<VoceMenu> getVoceMenuList() {        
    return voceMenuList;}

}
```

This is my jsp page, where I print in a input-text the fields of the object VoceMenu, in order to edit the value

```
<c:forEach items="${menu.voceMenuList}" var="item">
...
    URL <form:input path="${item.url}"/><br/>
...
</c:forEach>
```

but i get this error, because Spring thinks that "/admin/homeAdmin"  is a field of the class Menu, but actually it is just the value of the field 'URL' of the object VoceMenu!

```
   org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property '/admin/homeAdmin' of bean class [com.springgestioneerrori.model.Menu]: Bean property '/admin/homeAdmin' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:729)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:721)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:219)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:164)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:151)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:126)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.manageMenu_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f3(manageMenu_jsp.java:481)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.manageMenu_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(manageMenu_jsp.java:439)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.manageMenu_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(manageMenu_jsp.java:296)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.manageMenu_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fif_005f1(manageMenu_jsp.java:244)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.manageMenu_jsp._jspService(manageMenu_jsp.java:95)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:684)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:678)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.UntypedAttributeRenderer.write(UntypedAttributeRenderer.java:61)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:669)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:337)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:234)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:211)
    org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTag.doEndTag(RenderTag.java:220)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.default_.template1_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f2(template1_jsp.java:254)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.template.default_.template1_jsp._jspService(template1_jsp.java:110)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:241)
    org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:222)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:103)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:669)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:689)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:643)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:626)
    org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:322)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView.renderMergedOutputModel(TilesView.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

Comment: That won't work (and neither will this work as a workaround for the issue in the other thread you need indexed collections). Add the `varStatus` property and use that to construct the proper path. `path="${menu.voceMenuList[status.index].url}"` when the `varStatus="status"`.

Comment: I already tried what u say, but i got the error i wrote here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30617455/jsp-page-gives-me-a-list-but-my-class-want-a-set/30619347?noredirect=1#comment49305674_30619347

That's why i tried following this new way, according to what some users suggested me

Comment: Which won't work... It will never work regardless of what you try due to the fact the underlying collection is a `Set`. It will only work (third time is a charm) with indexed collections (lists) or an array...

Comment: Thank you man, you are very patient. I turned VoceMenu into List and I used the syntax you  wrote. Now I don't get that error. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok one quick question -

Have you binded this value (path="${item.url}") to a springForm ?

I guess issue here is controller can't able to find binding object of "/admin/homeAdmin"

For example when ever use the spring tag **form:input path="someValue"** you need to bind this propery(here "someValue") to a form as below

```
public class VoceMenuForm {
    private String someValue;
    public String getsomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }
    public void setsomeValue(String someValue) {
        this.someValue= someValue;
    }
}
```

**